# Android TextView 3 lines with horitontal scroll

Tags: android, scroll, textview

I have a long text in a textview. I want the full text 3 lines displayed with horizontal scroll.
For example, this is the phone screen :

```
!-------------!  
!             !
!             !
!             !
!             !
!             !
!             !
!-------------!
!this is the text i want 3 lines and
!with an horizontal scroll and carriages
!return must be auto to fit in 3 lines max
!<-- scroll -->
!-------------!
```

Tried everything i could unsuccessfully...

Comment: You can try `webview` instead

Answer (score 1):

1. Make 3 lined text from your string manually(replace 3 spaces with "\n").
2. Put your TextView with width="wrap_content" in HorisontalScrollView